# Can someone help me with Regular Expression in .net

Tags: .net, regex, asp.net-core, annotations

Can someone help me modify this

```
[RegularExpression(@"([0-9]+)", ErrorMessage = "Must be a Number.")]
```

to become like this form.
Example 12345678X eight numbers and the last char is an alphabetic character.

Comment: What the `12345678X` means? Is it hexadecimal string? If you meant 8 digit hexadecimal ended with the `X` you can use the following pattern: **"[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}X"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will solve your issue

```
[Test]
public void RegexTest()
{
    var regex = new Regex("^[0-9]{8}[A-Za-z]$");
    Assert.IsTrue(regex.IsMatch("12345678A"));
    Assert.IsFalse(regex.IsMatch("12345678AB"));
}
```